# System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Unable to Identify the error after publishing the file

**at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at Inspection.Apis.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Users\me_mo\source\InspectionBackend\Inspection.Apis\Startup.cs:line 66**

Line 66 is Swagger configuration

I tried to run also on release mode and its running fine.

Finding out this error just on deployment

```
 namespace Inspection.Apis
 {
 public class Startup
 {
     public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         Environment = environment;
         Configuration = configuration;
     }
     public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }

     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperMappings).Assembly);
         services.AddDbContext<InspectionEfContext, InspectionContext>();
         services.AddDbContext<InspectionContext>();
         services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
         services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
         services.AddCors(options =>
         {
             options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                 builder =>
                 {
                     builder
                     .AllowAnyOrigin()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowCredentials();
                 });
         });
         EntityFrameworkManager.ContextFactory = context =>
         {
             return new InspectionContext((context as InspectionContext).RequestInfo);
         };
         services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
         {
             options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Inspection Suite API", Version = "v1" });
             options.OperationFilter<TenantParameterOperationFilter>();


             options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
                 new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                 {
                     Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
                     Name = "Authorization",
                     In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                     Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                     Scheme = "Bearer"
                 });
             options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                     {
                         new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                         {
                             Reference = new OpenApiReference
                             {
                                 Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                 Id = "Bearer"
                             },
                             Scheme = "oauth2",
                             Name = "Bearer",
                             In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                         },
                         new List<string>() }
                 });
         });


               #region JWT
         var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]);
         services.AddAuthentication(x =>
         {
             x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
         .AddJwtBearer(x =>
         {
             x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
             x.SaveToken = true;
             x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
             {
                 ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                 IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                 ValidateIssuer = false,
                 ValidateAudience = false
             };
         });
         #endregion


         services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
         {
             options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

             if (Environment.IsProduction())
             {
                 options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                 options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
             }
         });



         services.AddScoped<IRequestInfo>(provider =>
         {
             var context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
             var claims = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;

             return new RequestInfo(this.Configuration, int.TryParse(claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == "tenantId")?.Value, out int tenantId) ? (int?)tenantId : null);
         });
         services.AddScoped<RequestScope<InspectionContext>>(provider =>
         {
             var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<InspectionContext>();
             var scope = provider.GetRequiredService<RequestScope>();
             var userId = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == "UserId")?.Value;
             return new RequestScope<InspectionContext>(scope.ServiceProvider, dbContext, scope.Logger, scope.Mapper, userId, scope.TenantId);
         });
         services.AddScoped<RequestScope<InspectionEfContext>>(provider =>
         {
             var dbContext = provider.GetRequiredService<InspectionEfContext>();
             var scope = provider.GetRequiredService<RequestScope>();
             var userId = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User.FindFirst(x => x.Type == "UserId")?. Value;
             return new RequestScope<InspectionEfContext>(scope.ServiceProvider, dbContext, scope.Logger, scope.Mapper, userId, scope.TenantId);
         });
         services.AddScoped<RequestScope>(provider =>
         {
             var logger = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
             var context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
             var claims = context.HttpContext.User.Claims;
             var userId = claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == "UserId")?.Value;
             var tenantId = int.TryParse(claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type == "tenantId")?.Value, out int t) ? t : default(int?);
             if (!tenantId.HasValue)
             {
                 tenantId = int.TryParse(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["tenantId"].SingleOrDefault(), out t) ? t : default(int?);
             }
             var mapper = provider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();

             return new RequestScope(provider, logger, mapper, userId, tenantId);
         });
         ConfigureRepositories(services);
         ConfigureAppServices(services);
     }
     private void ConfigureRepositories(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderTypeRepository, FormBuilderTypeRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderRepository, FormBuilderRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderQuestionsRepository, FormBuilderQuestionsRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderQuestionsResponseRepository, FormBuilderQuestionsResponseRepository>();
     }
     private void ConfigureAppServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserServices>();
         services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
         services.AddScoped<UserIdGenerator>();

         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderTypeServices, FormBuilderTypeServices>();

         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderServices, FormBuilderServices>();
         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderQuestionsServices, FormBuilderQuestionsServices>();
         services.AddScoped<IFormBuilderQuestionsResponseServices, FormBuilderQuestionsResponseServices>();

     }



     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
     {
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         }
         else
         {
             // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
             app.UseHsts();
         }
         app.UseMiddleware<InspectionExceptionMiddleware>();
         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
         {
             ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
         });
         app.UseCors("AllowAll");
         app.UseAuthentication();
         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseSwagger();
         app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
         {
             c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Inspection API V1");
             c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
         });

         app.UseMvc();
     }
 }
 public class TenantParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
 {
     public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
     {
         if (operation.Parameters == null)
             operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

         operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
         {
             Name = "tenantId",
             In = ParameterLocation.Header,
             Description = "Tenant Id"
         });
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Configuration["JwtKey"] is probably null, so it is likely that your setting is missing for release config

Comment: I have placed JWTKEY in appsetting.development
Should i place it appsetting ??

Comment: Thanks its solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//need to do initialization value in --->  appsettings.json <---- folder
// i did this

```
{
  "JWT": {
    "ServerSecret": "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456",
    "Issuer": "https://awesome.io",
    "Audience": "https://app.awesome.io"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After Yegor Androsov views i reviewed and find out he was right
Configuration[JwtKey] was null due to it was not placed in appsetting.json 
it was placed in appsetting.development.json

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure when referencing the key and value in appsetting.json,
use Configuration["JwtKey:Secret"]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30344540)